# npx tailwind init (tailwind css setting up)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, npx

[Error shown via image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krTfl.png)

So basically I am new to tailwind and I was trying to set up tailwind CSS by its documentation but as the image shows there are some errors which I am not able to understand . also when I am trying to use "npx tailwind init" it shows error as shown in the image. Also it is showing error in the input file created for the script. Please check out if you can help to  solve the problem, it'll be great help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

npx tailwindcss init -p

npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```